# How do I capture photos off of a blu-ray player onto my PC?

Tags: windows-7, video, recording, screen-capture

I would like to automatically capture a photo every 10 seconds off of my BBC Planet Earth blu-ray (since it is 1080p) and put them in a folder on my computer (for windows 7 rotating backgrounds).

How can I do this?

Comment: You can take manual screenshots in VLC player. Not sure if you could automate it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blu Ray forum](http://forum.blu-ray.com/blu-ray-technology-news/67500-blu-ray-movies-screen-capture.html)

> Cyberlink specifically removed the screenshot feature from PowerDVD Ultra version 8 for Blu-ray, so I can only assume there has been some pressure from the BDA or other vested parties to discourage screenshot taking. I would not be surprised if Arcsoft were under similar pressure. All of the open solutions require a "Step 0" which is probably the source of most of the hesitancy around posting specific methods. I will say that none of the open solutions work with copy-protected material and leave the details and extrapolation of that as an exercise for the sly reader.
>   With that being said, I personally prefer to dump many pre-generated bitmaps and sort through the results with a nice image browser, rather than trying to locate and frame step to specific shots while watching the movie (which can be troublesome with BD-Java navigation restrictions). My current method uses mplayer to dump all the I-frames of a movie file. These occur between 1-2 per second, so doing this typically results in 7000-10000 image files to sort through at a total cost of approximately 10-15GB of disc space.